# Can you set up a game on this website?

Tags: discussion

Hi I'm from Langdon School and we are making an educational game and I was wondering if you can set up a game on this website? If so, how?

Comment: Would recommend unity for setting up beginner games. If you google game hosting you can find many sites for helping host games if that's what you're after.

Comment: If you're looking to host a game, try itch.io

Answer (score 6):

No. I believe you misunderstand the purpose of the site. This is a site for asking questions and answering questions. We don't develop games on the site, host games on the site or anything like that. Get a quick overview of the site here: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/tour